# Update CouchDB with corrupt views 1.7.1 -> 3.0

Tags: python, couchdb

I want to finally update my couch db 1.7.1 to version 2 and then to 3, but I'm having some problems with  couchup. Due to corrupt view documents (bug in ektorp) in all tables, the watch in the couchup utility is not terminating. However, I do not want to deactivate the guard to ensure all documents have been replicated correctly.

The views have a reduced function of the format:

```
reduce null
```

Which is not a valid state from version > 2.0. What is the best way to update all design documents and remove all reduce functions which have this format?

I guess I could get all design docs by:

```
GET /db/_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"
```

and filter afterwards for all 'views'

However, I'm struggling to write a python script to remove the reduce function from all documents.